# How to create a link to script on linux

Tags: linux, function, unix, hyperlink, sh

I have a script `'/etc/storage/tg.sh'`.

Every time I need it, I have to write `'/etc/storage/tg.sh'`

How can I create a link and make it a function at the root? For example, like so 'tg text'?

I created -> `ln /etc/storage/tg.sh tg` and create link on `/opt/home/admin` but that's not what I need.

For example, I need some like logger or date function
[i need my new function here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RenJ9.png) how to do this?

Comment: You can move it to a directory that's in your `PATH`, add `/etc/storage` to your `PATH`, or make a link to the script in a directory that is in your `PATH`.

Comment: How did that file get to that place in the first place?  One easy fix would be to create a function within your `~/.bash_profile`, something like `tg () (/etc/storage/tg.sh $@)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try `ln /etc/storage/tg.sh /opt/home/admin/tg`. Would that work for you?

UPDATE: fixed the path in the command.

Comment: i don't have thats directory, after my link  i have file here ```home/admin/tg```

Answer (score 0):

Make a symlink using `ln -s` like so:

```
ln -s /etc/storage/tg.sh /opt/home/admin/tg
```

Add this directory to your `PATH`, for example add this to your `~/.profile` file:

```
export PATH="/opt/home/admin:${PATH}"
```